How do I check if multiple random chances are 1 efficiently?
So, I have 4 chances (chance1, chance2, etc.). I want to check if one chance is equal to one, but none of the other ones are one. I know I could just check every single one, but I'm eventually going to add more and more chances, and the list will be really long and annoying to deal with.
var chance1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
var chance2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1
var chance3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1
var chance4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1

if (chance1 === 1) {
  document.body.innerText = "Red - 1 in 10"
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red"
}

if (chance2 === 1) {
  document.body.innerText = "Orange - 1 in 100"
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "orange"
}

if (chance3 === 1) {
  document.body.innerText = "Yellow - 1 in 1,000"
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"
}

if (chance4 === 1) {
  document.body.innerText = "Green - 1 in 10,000"
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green"
}

Again, I tried checking every single value, it works, but I think it would be best to have a more efficient way to this.

Use an array and loop over it.

Use an array to dynamically calculate your chances, then iterate over it to set your text and background color.

Make it an array of objects containing the number limit, random value, and color.

@i_suckatcode, read how to create an array and then read how to iterate over array

Arrays are basic JS, so really: start with a good (modern) JS tutorial that teaches the language basics, take a day to run through that, and then revisit this. And then rely on MDN any time you need to look something up.

plenty of relevant answer. Finding value: How do I check if an array includes a value in JavaScript?. Finding duplicatesRemove duplicate values from JS array

So you want to update the page to show the least likely event that happened?
Store your chances in an array, along with the color that corresponds with that chance. There are several ways to do this, one would be to store them as an object that looks like this
{
  chance: 1000,
  color: 'green',
}

Store the chances in reverse order, meaning test the least likely scenario first, as opposed to checking the most likely and then overwriting afterward.
So the full code might look something like this


const chances = [
  { chance: 10000, color: 'green' },
  { chance: 1000, color: 'yellow' },
  { chance: 100, color: 'orange' },
  { chance: 10, color: 'red' },
];

function determineChance() {
  for (let {chance, color} of chances) {
    const roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * chance) + 1;
    if (roll === 1) {
       const capColor = color[0].toUpperCase() + color.slice(1);
       document.body.innerText = `${capColor} - 1 in ${chance}`;
       document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
       
       return;
    }
  }
  
  // If here, no hits
  document.body.innerText = 'No hits';
}

determineChance();




This works, but is there any way to make it also have the second letter? When I use this script, it works, but it also removes the second letter of the colors (when it displays it in document.body.innerText = 'something').

Yeah, I had a typo with slice. It should have been slice(1) instead of slice(2). The snippet is updated.

You can break this down into smaller; logical functions.

determineChance ~ Get the chance, and update the document
getRandomChance ~ Find a chance, where the random value is 0
formatMessage ~ Format the message, based on the chance data
randInt ~ Generate a random integer



const chanceArr = [
  { limit: 10_000 , color: 'green'  },
  { limit:  1_000 , color: 'yellow' },
  { limit:    100 , color: 'orange' },
  { limit:     10 , color: 'red'    },
];


const determineChance = () => {
  const chance = getRandomChance();
  document.body.innerText = formatMessage(chance); // Always show message
  if (chance) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = chance.color; // If applicable
  }
};

const getRandomChance = () => chanceArr.find(({ limit }) => {
  const randomIndex = randInt(limit);
  console.log(JSON.stringify({ limit, randomIndex })); // DEBUG
  return randomIndex === 0;
});

const formatMessage = (chance) => chance
  ? `${capitalize(chance.color)} - 1 in ${chance.limit.toLocaleString()}`
  : 'No hits';

const randInt = (max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
const capitalize = (str) => str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);

determineChance(); // Main entry-point



Here is an example of a 1/100 roll:

